# Error while adding Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert .ppt files to .pdf.

I am using VS10 and I have office 2007 installed.

I have added reference to  office.dll Version=12.

my problem is when I try to compile the application, it gives no error but when I am running the application and reach the 
function which has the code to convert ppt to pdf it throws an exception

```
"Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.Microsoft.Office.Core, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
```

If I try to add Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library dll system throws other errors like there is a conflict between both the dll's.

please help.

Comment: Check GAC assembly version

Comment: Perhaps your MS Office is corrupted and you have to reinstall it. In any case, bear in mind that what you need is adding a reference to the specific Office program (Microsoft PowerPoint 12.0 Object Library in this case).

Comment: i don't think my MS Office is Corrupted it is working fine. other than that i have added Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.dll also.

Comment: I haven't ever seem this error (and I have used Office automation quite a few times). If you search for this error, all the reference you would find are related to not having installed Office. Even in case of having some kind of incompatibility between Office 2007 and VS 2010, you wouldn't get this error anyway. On the other hand, if the PowerPoint reference works fine, you can remove the Office one because actually you don't need it for anything.

Comment: 1)Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.ApplicationClass appppt = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.ApplicationClass();
                    2)Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation pptfl = null;                                             3)pptfl = appppt.Presentations.Open(input, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse);   for (3) i need office .dll

Comment: for third (3) point it says that "The type 'Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'office, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'."